# Several posts with incorrect image Markdown syntax

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, images, markdown-rendering

I've noticed several questions and answers posted recently, typically from newer users, where the image Markdown syntax is incorrect (using the link syntax instead of image syntax. In other words, missing the leading `!`).  Many of them still have "Enter image description" text in them, which leads me to suspect the incorrect syntax is being generated by a template and/or editor feature rather than by the users themselves.

Specifically, when it should look like this:
`![enter image description here][1]`

It actually looks like this: `[enter image description here][1]`

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44439720/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44424793/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44424904/revisions (rev 4)
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44424554/revisions (rev 2)

I was unable to reproduce the issue myself.

Comment: I have a feeling that the user is deleting the ! themselves because the editor puts the syntax right on the end of their text and they insert a line break in the wrong place (and then think "I don't want an exclamation point here" and remove it).  And then don't preview the result.

Comment: originally I thought so too, but the frequency of occurrence seemed to indicate a more systematic issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

New users cannot embed images into their posts - that's something that's unlocked at 10 reputation along with being able to post more than two links at all. It's easy to just remove the `!` at the front and change it to a link, though, so it can either be embedded later or another user can embed it for them.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  It's been long enough since I was a new user, I totally forgot about that restriction :)