# Encourage people to post an image as an image rather than [enter image descriptions here]

Tags: discussion, edits, images, specific-edit, image-upload

Does SO really encourage people to post an image as an image rather than `[enter image description here][1]`?

Since, I have stated answering questions on Stack Overflow, I think I have edited most of the questions just to change that [enter image description here](https://image) to image.

And now I tested it by myself to check if SO really tells me to post an image as an image or just like that.

Test result:

1. If I just click on that "paste" then it asks me to provide a link and after I provide the link and do add an image then it does this `[![enter image description here][1]][1]`. *Which is normal*
2. If I do the same from "browse" then I also get the same result. `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` *Which is normal*
3. And the third method is "drag and drop" which is exactly similar to "browser".

So, the main question is ***Where do people really miss this part?*** Do people try to edit it by themselves? But really, I have found this issue in more then 50% of the people who had posted the image. Do *"50%"* of the people try to edited that part by themselves? Shouldn't SO try discourage them to do this? Is SO trying to do this?

I have found this question of 4 years ago, [Several posts with incorrect image Markdown syntax](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350382/several-posts-with-incorrect-image-markdown-syntax), but up to now also it is the issue for most of the questions.

A solving suggestion is, if people try to edit these link parts then we can alert them or while making that link we can suggest people to not edit this part or at least that `!`.

We should encourage people not to edit that image syntax because we helper just have click on that image link to see what is there and if that image part is described in question then we have to do back and forth. So, we should encourage people to not to edit it by themselves, because the default is perfectly fine. ***Is SO really doing this? Is SO really encouraging people not to edit that part of the image?***

---

I don't think anyone here is really understanding the question. The question is not "Is there any existing feature to discourage people to not edit the image part because I don't really think if there is anything think". The question is "Don't we have to discourage people to do that?". It is not that about privilege of 10 or more rep; it is the general question.

---

Here are the example : [Results for "[enter image description]"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%5Benter+image+description+here%5D%22).

*For me there are 50*801 = 40,050 questions.*

Comment: Isn't there a rep limit for embedding images into posts?

Comment: @BDL I believe there is but what about other people? I have found this in other people also!

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11682469)

Comment: The question you linked to was answered by an SO employee and mentions the rep limit.

Comment: @JeanneDark I am not telling, questioning on code or error. I am just asking in general. Yeah! I know most of the people post code or error in image.

Comment: @Xitiz: Are you sure that the people had the rep before posting? But we will never now for sure why people do something unless one of this people tell you. I should add, that I've rarely seen users that aren't restricted post links instead of embedding.

Comment: "Does people try to edit it by themselves" - sure, why not. Maybe they don't want the images to be inline, who knows. Maybe they saw it as a typo and corrected it. It is not out of the ordinary to believe this is the case, especially since you did your due diligence and made sure the automated ways to embed an image are working as designed.

Comment: @BDL Yeah! I am sure they have enough reputation to post image but I am saying that SO doesn't really discourage people to not edit that image part which is okay in default.

Comment: @Gimby so, can't we encourage people not to do that. Cuz in the most... 50% of the edit I just have to edit for that only! And additionally it is not just a case in/about inline.

Comment: @Xitiz I think that if you give some examples, people will prove to you that "50% of the edit I just have to edit that only" is actually false. Everyone makes mistakes, including you.

Comment: @Gimby I am taking in average, I am not taking with any stats result here and it could be either 40/30 or 60/70! I am just telling that I have edited that part (not only but including that part) in most of the question which contains image. And yeah! Anyone could be wrong you, me,.. anyone. Additionally ***that stat is not the main part of the question!!!***

Comment: What concretely would such an encouragement be? Under what conditions would it trigger?

Comment: @Xitiz Can you link to 1 or 2 examples where you had to fix such a mistake?

Comment: @Xitiz: It's not about an exact number, but if you want the company to invest developer time into a feature, you have to show somehow that this is a big enough problem to warrant the costs. Out of curiosity, I checked your last 120 edits (just quickly, so numbers might be +-): You have ~10 times embedded an image, non of the original authors had enough rep to do it themselves at the point of posting. This also coincides with my own experience that not embedded images are mostly done by people who are not allowed to embed themselves.

Comment: @BDL then my question is just a spam? There is no such problem in SO, right?

Comment: @Xitiz: No, I'm not saying that. I just say that the problem (out of my experience) is not big enough to require an automatic solution. I might be wrong and the problem might be bigger than I expect it, but that needs some evidence. The meta question here definitely isn't bad, most of the downvotes here are probably because people think that the features isn't needed, not because the question is bad.

Comment: @BDL Can this question be edited to something really needed things? I think  this issue exist in SO.

Comment: @Xitiz: You could, for example, go to the data explorer and try to query how many edits are done which embed images into posts where the author had more than 10 rep at the time of posting. That would at least give a base estimate of how much time the requested feature would be solving.

Comment: @BDL Okay! I will definitely try to do this. But I afraid this question will be closed/underrated because of downvote and my effort doesn't change/support this question after that edit.

Comment: @Xitiz: I wouldn't expect the question to be closed. About the votes: If your feature is really needed by people, then votes will balance out. Either because they find your feature request, or because they ask a similar one and get duplicate closed. The chances of getting any feature request implemented in the near future isn't big anyway. You can just look at [how many other requests there are](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed+-status-deferred+-status-declined) which do have hundreds of votes and aren't touched yet.

Comment: My problem with this is it promotes using images, something that, at this time, we shouldn't be doing. Maybe in the future images won't be as poor an information source as it currently is, but for now pretty much the only time you want an image in a question is when the question is about the image, like "how did this code <code> produce this rendering artefact <image>?" In an answer the image should be supplementary information, like "The mistake was <description of problem> and can be solved with <solution>. See? <image>"

Comment: I am not promoting people to post image, I am asking if we can make sure to post image as image rather then enter image description! @user4581301 have you really read the question completely? But anyway I found this question should be deleted but I am unable to deleted because it has one answer. :( I now believe I am wrong or this question is just a spam here! I don't know, I am not asking the well question or this is not an issue in SO, I have found this issue many times so, I had posted but according to all these comments and answer now I started thinking this is not an issue here.

Comment: I have read the question. You may not be promoting the use of images, but the proposed change makes it easier to post images, and if it is easier to post images, more images will be posted. The use of images has been promoted despite your intent.

Comment: @user4581301 In that sense you are definitely right, but I am not taking about that anyway, neither I had said "people should post image of question/code, they don't have to provide text of the code." Have I said that anywhere, why are you assuming that. I am just saying that in most of the question markdown is text rather then image, where image is important. Don't SO really need image, don't questioner should provided image in anytime? Then why is image posting option there. So, if they are posting an image then we should encourage people not to edit that markdown. I am just saying that.

Comment: Now I started thinking my question is not clear to people or there is no such issue for anyone in stackoverflow. My question is changed to, how can I delete it because I don't think this question is really necessary for future  cuz there is not such issue here additionally this question is not clear also. But my personal experience is, there is this issue in SO, which I don't know if this is a major issue or not but it is an issue, this question is not making any sense. :(

Comment: What do you mean by *"because we helper just have click"* (seems incomprehensible)? Can you fix it?

Comment: This question could become clearer by adding an example. For example, an example of correct and incorrect (Markdown source, formatted as code to make it very clear it is literal).

Comment: @PeterMortensen we have to click on that link open that image in another tag, and we have to do back and forth rather then, if there will be an image then, it would be very much easier, we don't have to click on that link, we don't have to go back and fourth.........

Comment: I stopped looking after 5 posts from the search query, but they were all by users below 10 rep and most of them are closed anyway.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have tested it in more then 500 questions and found in average more then 20%(120 questions) of the people have edited that markdown. Tested result is automated, tested for rep>20.

Comment: @Xitiz Testing for >20 rep is not relevant at all. The rep at the time of posting would be the relevant number.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz To check if there were 10 rep while posting question required hunam testing, and I am not that much active to do that clearly! I can't test 500 links one by one and decide that rather then that I would delete my question, neither I am any staff of SO or I am moderator of SO. So, I have questioned as just a normal user. And I will do research as that and expect answer as normal user as well.

Comment: The question is already closed, ***if there is no problem as I mentioned then I don't want any further answer.*** You don't have to waste time in it, I have asked question personally and with personal experience ..... I have personally felt it while answering/editing question so I had asked here.

Answer (score 3):

New users (rep less than 10) can't create posts with inline images. Any image they add is made into a link like that. See [Update Help Center > Privileges > Remove New User Restrictions to note inline images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376733/6083675)

I haven’t seen this happen with users who can post inline images. When I’ve seen a user with 10+ rep with a post like this, it’s been because they’ve gained that reputation since posting.

Comment: I believe there is but what about other people? I have found this in other people also!

Comment: @Xitiz - I have never experienced it.  If you are reporting a bug you will have to be more precise in your description of the problem.

Comment: If there is that privilege then, why I am editing 50% of the question?

Comment: @SecurityHound I am not reporting it as a bug but I am asking SO to encourage people to not edit that part of the image. Or something cuz all of the option in image is perfectly working and the issue must be edited by people themselves.

Comment: @Xitiz - The community prefers inline screenshots.  I am not sure what you are suggesting.  That is an indication your question is not clear.

Comment: @SecurityHound I think I am not understanding what do you mean by _inline screenshot_? Ok, if it is not clear for you then, just answer it. Does SO really discourage people to edit `[![Enter image description]][1]` to `[[Enter image description]][1]`?

Comment: One of those will inline the screenshot within the post the other only generates a link to the image.  If you don’t know what “inline” means, you will have to look it up, the words definition explains itself. Use a sample image, edit your question, and actually use the syntax your asking about to fully understand the differences

Comment: @Xitiz I had to get to second page of your revisions to find one where you'd inlined an image, and it was indeed a user with <10 rep: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68645224/revisions.

Comment: *I have found this in other people also!* @Xitiz Are you sure that the OP had more than 10 rep when they made their post? If you're looking at a post that is old or has up votes, then it's likely the OP didn't have enough reputation to post an image at the time and got their current rep afterward..

Comment: Yeah! I believe that was the issue there. @BSMP